# Different gibbs energy equations

Tags: physical-chemistry

For temperature dependence of Gibbs energy, Why we  Gibbs-Helmholtz equation rather than finding directly in the same way as Gibbs energy dependence on pressure?

$$\frac{\mathrm dG}{\mathrm dp} = V \Rightarrow \mathrm dG = V\,\mathrm dp \quad\text{for solids and liquids}$$

By pressure I mean external pressure applied. Like for gases $\mathrm dG = nRT \ln(p_\mathrm f/p_\mathrm i)$. Why we use this equation $(G/T)/T = H/T^2$ for change in Gibbs energy dependence of temperature. Why not this equation $\mathrm dG = \mathrm dT\times(-S)$?

Comment: Please add more detail such as what you mean by "Gibbs energy dependence *on* pressure". Temperature and pressure are not the same variable, so your question does not make sense.

Comment: dG/dP = V => dG = dP*V (For Solids and liquids).
By pressure i mean external pressure applied. Like for Gases dG = nRT In(pf/pi). Why we use this equation (G/T)/T = H/T^2 for change in gibbs energy dependence of temperature. Why not this equation dG = dT*(-S)

Comment: I added your clarification directly  to the post.

Comment: See the bottom of the Wikipedia page for the Gibbs-Helmholtz equation for a useful derivation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Helmholtz_equation

Answer (score 1):

> Why we use this equation [and ...] not this equation?

It depends what problem you want to solve.

$\frac{dG}{dT}$ is of interest, for example, if you want to know the maximum work available from a process at different temperatures.

$\frac{d(G/T)}{dT}$ is of interest, for example, if you want to know how the equilibrium constant changes with temperature (because $\Delta G^\circ = -R T \ln K$).